What constellation was the sun on in August 5, 2001 BC
In what constellation was the sun on August 5, 2001 BC

Stellarium (https://stellarium.org/) can easily tell you that.

Are you asking about the astronomical constellations, or are  you asking about the astrological sectors of the sky.  The question is hyper focussed, It's hard to imagine any practical use for this kind of fact.  Of course "August" didn't even exist in 2001 BC

https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&COMMAND=10&CENTER=500%40399&CAL_FORMAT=B&CAL_TYPE=G&TLIST=%27BC+2001-Aug-5+12%3A00%27&QUANTITIES=%2729%2C31%27

Which calendar?  Proleptic Gregorian, or proleptic Julian?

@JamesK The concept of BC didn't exist in 2001 BC, either.

If you are asking about the Gregorian calendar, then according to this Horizons script (made by PM 2Ring), the Sun was in Virgo on August 5, 2001 BC. If you are asking about the Julian calendar, then according to Universe Today, the Sun is in Leo in August, and hence would have been there on August 5, 2001 BC.

Wouldn't the Sun have been in a different constellation 4000 years ago due to precession?

@JohnHoltz Yes, it was in the constellation of Virgo on that Gregorian date, according to my Horizons query above. But if the date is Julian, then the constellation was Leo.
